# Convergence of vector of RV iff convergence of each RV

Tags: probability, convergence

I'm trying to show that:
$$
(X_n,Y_n)\to^p(X,Y)\iff X_n\to^pX,Y_n\to^p Y
$$
where $\to^p$ means convergence in probability ($P(||X_n-X||>\varepsilon)\to 0,\forall\varepsilon>0$).

I managed to show $(\Rightarrow)$, but I don't know how to show $(\Leftarrow)$.

**Question:** How to prove that 
$$\{||(X_n,Y_n)-(X,Y)||>\varepsilon\}\subseteq\{||X_n-X||>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}\cup\{||Y_n-Y||>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}
$$

Comment: @GuihermeSalome I need to show the same thing but I don't know how to show the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction. It seems like it should be obvious that if $(X_{n},Y_{n})\to^{P} (X,Y)$ that we should have $X_{n} \to^{P} X$ and $Y_{n} \to^{P} Y$, but I'm sure it's not that simple. How did you do it?

Comment: @GuihermeSalome also, if you have to prove that  $\{||(X_n,Y_n)-(X,Y)||>\varepsilon\}\subseteq\{||X_n-X||>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}\cup\{||Y_n-Y||>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}$, do you also have to prove that $\{||X_n-X||>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}\cup\{||Y_n-Y||>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\} \subseteq \{||(X_n,Y_n)-(X,Y)||>\varepsilon\}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is all you're trying to prove let's rewrite some things and see if that helps.  I assume we are working with Euclidean distance here.

Suppose $\|(X_n,Y_n) - (X,Y)\| > \epsilon$ and $\|X_n - X\| \leq \epsilon/2$.  We want to show that $\|Y_n - Y\| > \epsilon/2$, then by symmetry we're done.

So we're assuming
\begin{eqnarray}
(X_n - X)^2 + (Y_n - Y)^2 &>& \epsilon^2, \\
(X_n - X)^2 &\leq& \epsilon^2/4.
\end{eqnarray}
And we are trying to show that

$$
(Y_n - Y)^2 > \epsilon^2/4.
$$

Should I let you take it over from here?

Comment: if you would't mind completing this proof, I would be very much appreciative! How does this help us?

Comment: also, if you could answer the questions I asked the OP above, because I doubt he cares to revisit a question he asked 2 years ago, I would be forever grateful to you! :)

Comment: @Jeff hey there, I might be wrong butwhat you are asking might be Slutky’s theorem.

Comment: @GuilhemeSalome it's related to Slutsky's Theorem, but it's not exactly.

Comment: @Jeff I found what theorem it is (we call it the "magic" theorem here haha). Shoot me an email at guilhermesalome at gmail.com and I'll send you a pdf with it.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé thanks, but I think I figured it out.